How do I implement a Swiftui app that allow user to navigate through pages, and make zoom to destination area
We are working on a Swiftui application that allows users to open some PDF files. The files have some internal links. When user tap a link, it should scroll to the specific page and zoom to the area where the link points at.
The following code performs the scroll to the destination page but does not make zoom to the destination rectangle.
import PDFKit
import SwiftUI

class CustomPDFView: PDFView {
    var onAnnotationClick: ((PDFAnnotation, CGRect, PDFDestination?) -> Void)?
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch")
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        
        if let page = self.page(for: location, nearest: true) {
            let pagePoint = convert(location, to: page)
            if let annotation = page.annotation(at: pagePoint) {
                let annotationRect = annotation.bounds
                let destination = annotation.destination
                onAnnotationClick?(annotation, annotationRect, destination)
            }
        }
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
}

extension PDFAnnotation {
    var destination: PDFDestination? {
        guard let action = self.action as? PDFActionGoTo else { return nil }
        return action.destination
    }
}

struct PDFViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    let pdfDocument: PDFDocument
    @Binding var currentPage: PDFPage?
    @Binding var pdfView: CustomPDFView
    var onAnnotationClick: ((PDFAnnotation, CGRect, PDFDestination?) -> Void)?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomPDFView {
        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        
        
        pdfView.onAnnotationClick = onAnnotationClick
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomPDFView, context: Context) {
        if let page = currentPage {
            print(page.label as Any)
            uiView.go(to: page)
        }
    }
}


struct PDFViewer: View {
    @State private var pdfDocument: PDFDocument
    @State private var currentPage: PDFPage?
    @State private var navigationHistory: [PDFPage] = []
    @State var pdfView = CustomPDFView()
    
    init?(pdfDocument: PDFDocument) {
        self._pdfDocument = State(initialValue: pdfDocument)
        self._currentPage = State(initialValue: pdfDocument.page(at: 0))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                if navigationHistory.count > 1 {
                    Button(action: goBack) {
                        Text("Back")
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: previous) {
                    Text("Prev")
                }
                .padding()
                
                Button(action: goForward) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            
            PDFViewWrapper(pdfDocument: pdfDocument, currentPage: $currentPage, pdfView: $pdfView) { annotation, rect, destination in
                handleAnnotationClick(annotation: annotation, rect: rect, destination: destination)
            }
            .onChange(of: currentPage) {  newPage in
                if let newPage = newPage {
                    if let lastPage = navigationHistory.last, lastPage != newPage {
                        navigationHistory.append(newPage)
                    } else if navigationHistory.isEmpty {
                        navigationHistory.append(newPage)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func handleAnnotationClick(annotation: PDFAnnotation, rect: CGRect, destination: PDFDestination?) {
        print("Annotation tapped: \(annotation)")
        print("Annotation rect: \(rect)")
        if let destination = destination {
            print("Annotation destination: \(destination)")
            if let page = destination.page {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    currentPage = page
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func goBack() {
        if navigationHistory.count > 1 {
            navigationHistory.removeLast()
            currentPage = navigationHistory.last
        }
    }
    
    private func previous() {
        print(pdfView.currentPage?.annotations as Any)
    }
    
    private func goForward() {
        pdfView.go(to: pdfView.currentDestination!)
    }
}




struct ShowPdfView: View {
    @State private var pdfDocument: PDFDocument?
    let urlString: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let pdfDocument = pdfDocument {
                PDFViewer(pdfDocument: pdfDocument)
            } else {
                Text("Loading PDF...")
                    .onAppear(perform: loadPDF)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadPDF() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            if let url = URL(string: urlString),
               let document = PDFDocument(url: url) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.pdfDocument = document
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Handle PDF loading error
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


